# How to put two variables from separate functions into the same flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, math

I want the beginAge and the rrspStart variables to be outputted in the same function instead of separate ones so that I can perform calculations between them. I am not sure how to do these so far I have just learned how to get the variables outside of the slider slide: function itself. These are located at the bottom in ageLog function and startLog function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// Individual Variables

var age;

$("#ageSlide").slider({
    value: 72,
    min: 35,
    max: 85,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      age = ui.value;
      ageLog();
    }
});

// Individual Constants

var lifeLength = 100; // Life Expectancy

// Tax Constants

var mTr = 0.3; // Marginal Tax Rate
var dTr = 0.15; // Divided Tax Rate
var cGi = 0.5; // Capital Gains Inclusion for Tax

// RRSP Investment Variables

var rrspStart;

$( "#rrspStart" ).slider({
      value: 50000,
      min: 25000,
      max: 250000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        rrspStart = ui.value;
        startLog();
      }
});

//RRSP Investment Constants

var rrspRoR = 0.6; // RRSP Rate of Return

//RSIP Investment Info

var rsipDiR = 0.4; // RSIP Interest Rate
var rsipRor = 0.6; // RSIP Rate of Return
var pRsipDcG = 0.7; // Percent RSIP Deferred Capital Gains 70%
var pRsipI = 0.1; // Percent RSIP Interest
var pRsipD = 0.1; // Percent RSIP Dividend
var pRsipCg = 0.1; // Percent RSIP Capital Gains

//RSIP Calculation


  function ageLog(){
    var period = 1;
    var beginAge = age;
    console.log(beginAge);
  }

  function startLog(){
    console.log(rrspStart);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code posted.

`beginAge` in the function `ageLog` is nothing but `age`

```
var beginAge = age;
```

`age` is a `global variable` just like `rrspStart`, can be accessed from `startLog` function too.

But it's (`age`) value gets updated by the following code

```
$("#ageSlide").slider({
    value: 72,
    min: 35,
    max: 85,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      age = ui.value;
      ageLog();
    }
});
```

And value of `rrspStart` gets updated by the following code.

```
$( "#rrspStart" ).slider({
      value: 50000,
      min: 25000,
      max: 250000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        rrspStart = ui.value;
        startLog();
      }
});
```

Both the functions `startLog` and `ageLog` are invoked separately by different `elements`.

Instead of having two `functions` create single `function`.

```
function ageAndStartLog(){
    console.log(rrspStart);
    console.log(beginAge);
}
```

And use the same for both the user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it just like this

```
  function Log()
  {
    var period = 1;
    var beginAge = age;
    console.log("Begin age : " + beginAge);
    console.log(" rrspStart : " + rrspStart);
  }
```